# Store Half-Edge structure in CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm building an app that uses a [Half-Edge structure](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/The_Half-Edge_Data_Structure.shtml) to store a mesh of 2D triangles.

The mesh is calculated everytime a user taps the screen and adds a point.

I want to be able to save the mesh into CoreData. Not just the points, but the whole mesh, so it won't have to be recalculated again when restored)

My HalfEdge structure is like this (a drawing is composed by a set of triangles):

```
Triangle:
    - firstHalfEdge (actually, any half-edge of the triangle)
HalfEdge:
    - lastVertex (the Vertex in which the Edge ends)
    - next (next halfedge in the triangle)
    - oposite (the halfedge oposite to this one, which is in another triangle)
    - triangle (the triangle which this edge belongs to)
Vertex:
    - halfEdge (the edge which the vertex belongs to)
    - point (2d coordinates of the vertex)
```

And this is my CoreData scheme:
[image]

As you can see I added a previous attribute to HalfEdge (although is not needed) to avoid getting a warning for a non inverse relationship.

But I keep getting more warnings:

- Vertex.point should have an inverse. (no problem with this one, I'll just add another attribute)
- Vertex.halfEdge should have an inverse. (this refers to the HalfEdge for which this vertex is the first vertex, so lastVertex wouldn't do as an inverse)
- HalfEdge.lastVertex should have an inverse. (see above)
- HalfEdge.triangle should have an inverse. (Triangle.firstHalfEdge refers to just one edge, any, but all 3 edges should refer to the triangle) Triangle.firstHalfEdge should have an inverse. (see above)

So, what should I do? Should I try to accomplish those inverse relationships some how (though, I'm thinking it would get my structure calculation more complex) or should I ignore those warnings?

By the way, if anybody is curious, this is what I'm doing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2Eg7DXW7-A&feature=feedu

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the warnings by setting MOMC_NO_INVERSE_RELATIONSHIP_WARNINGS in project configuration editor (category "Data Model Version Compiler – Warnings" in Xcode 4.1) to YES ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL99N.png)).

Still, there are [things to consider](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW6) before doing so.

Comment: I know there are things to consider. I think disabling the warning is like turning off that blinking engine light in your car. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: In any case there *are* situations when having no inverse relationship is the best option. For my case (I'm being annoyed by the same warning) inverse is not making any sense at all. Probably a bad design, but I can't think of a better one.